# How to initialize a dictionary type during Dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to read a bunch of key value pairs from `appsettings.json` into a dictionary as part of registering the services:

```
services.AddScoped<AddressManager>(t =>
{
     const string PhoneBookSection = "PhoneBookSection";
     var phonebook = 
           Configuration.GetSettings<Dictionary<string, string>>($"{PhoneBookSection}:DummyConfiguration");               
     return new AddressManager(phonebook);
});
```

I'm getting this error during creation of this object:

> Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing
>   a public parameterless constructor.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a DI problem, and not a problem with how you are using `Configuration.GetSettings`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I'm not sure where the problem is.  I assumed it could be related to DI since the object creation fails during this phase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what on earth `Configuration.GetSettings<T>` is. I don't know and didn't found such a method in the .NET Core framework.

However, there's the [Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind) method which does exactly what you want to achieve:

```
services.AddScoped<AddressManager>(t =>
{
    const string PhoneBookSection = "PhoneBookSection";
    var phonebook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Configuration.Bind(PhoneBookSection, phonebook);
    return new AddressManager(phonebook);
});
```

You may need to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the same and the error persists : Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Check out and test [this sample program](https://gist.github.com/adams85/662ac5d2a03f236dc73f00bbfd9aebf8) I put together. This proves that my answer works perfectly so the problem must lie elsewhere. I can think of your appsettings.json or the constructor of *AddressManager*.